# LLVM : Remove back-edges from the loops in a function

Tags: loops, llvm

I have unrolled loops inside the file `a.bc` using the following command:
`opt -loops -loop-rotate -loop-simplify -loop-unroll -unroll-count=3 -unroll-allow-partial -debug a.bc -o a.loop.bc`
Now, I needed to remove back-edges from all the loops inside a function, say `F`. I thought of creating an llvm pass which will find the exit block from a loop(assume just 1 exit block) and then replace the back-edge with an edge to the exit block of every loop.
Is there a straight-forward way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

So if I am not mistaken you want to have a unique exit block for all loops ? if all of your loops have constant trip-count then there is not any phi node at the exit blocks and so it is rather easily to connect them, otherwise there are some exit phi nodes, then you should reconstruct them to preserve dominance property of SSA, which might not be straight forward, you can find different methods of doing it in chapter 5 of this book (you can download the book)  :
[SSA book](http://ssabook.gforge.inria.fr/latest/book.pdf)